# SQL select where a user has two groups at same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with user_id and group_id,i need to recover a list of users that are in both groups.

```
SELECT * FROM [user_group]
```

My table is something like this

```
User_Id   |  Group_id | 
=========================
1         |      1     
2         |      2    
1         |      3    
4         |      3    
4         |      5    
4         |      2     
4         |      1     
4         |      10
```

I need to recover the users that is in both group 1 and 3
So i need a select that recover user_id 1 and 4

What should i do?I tried to insert in a tempTable and select with IN and Or.

Comment: plz add section for desired output ?

Comment: @a did you actually read the question? It has the desired output

Comment: It's actually a good idea to specify the desired output as formatted text.

Comment: I agree, but just saying its not there means you didnt read the question!

Comment: Thanks @jarlh - that is what I meant by saying "section" word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`, where you use `having` combined with `count distinct` to return only User_Id's with both Group_id values.

```
select User_Id
from tablename
where Group_id in (1, 3)
group by User_Id
having count(distinct Group_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    [User_Id]
FROM
    [User_group]
WHERE
    [Group_Id] IN (1,3)
GROUP BY
    [User_Id]
HAVING
    COUNT(Group_id) > 1
```

Or another way (just for fun)

```
SELECT
    ug1.User_Id
FROM
    [user_group] ug1 JOIN [user_group] ug2
    ON ug1.User_Id = ug2.User_Id
WHERE
    ug1.Group_id =1 AND ug2.Group_id =3
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Saw it, and just fixed it.